# how to access collection view child ui elements

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

Hey everyone i have DotNet Maui project. I want to access child elements of my CollectionView. I don't want to do anything with their data so i don't think MVVM helps me here. I want to set an animation on the items that pass a certain x and y position.

**So in short how can i access the child elements of my CollectionView? Can i get their x and y positions?**
if i can't is there any solution for the animation i want to set? i want to have a fade and scale down animation to the items on CollectionView when the user scroll down. but whatever i do i can't access the child elements to set the animation.

Comment: I think, make a subclass of CollectionView. Try to do what you want in code-behind of that subclass. Maybe call `IVisualTreeElement.GetVisualChildren()`, OR override `OnChildAdded(child)`, and make your own list. OR you might have to write platform-specific handlers, to manipulate the physical UI elements on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView.GetVisualTreeDescendants()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).